# How to assign redirection symbol to a variable for assembling a command line

Tags: bash, shell, variables, redirect

I have a couple of BASH scripts that launch programs I commonly use with common arguments using variables for the command and arguments. The invocation appears at the end like so:

```
$PROGRAM $ARG1 $ARG2 &
```

Now I want to redirect output to stderr and stdout to `/dev/null` by default. I want to be able to disable that with a switch to the script (`-v` = verbose). But if I try to assign `"2>&1 > /dev/null"` to a var, say `REDIRECTION`, (clearing it if verbose is specified) and try to invoke like so:

```
$PROGRAM $ARG1 $ARG2 $REDIRECTION &
```

The redirection directives are passed as arguments to the program. Is there a way to do this? Or do I have to use my solution which is to have 2 separate invocation lines, one with and one without the redirection directives, depending on "verbosity"?

Answer (score 5):

One option is to use the `eval` builtin, which processes its arguments like a Bash command, handling things like redirection operators. However, `eval` is pretty risky, since it will reprocess *all* of its arguments, even ones that have already been processed properly, and this can cause bizarre or unsafe behavior if not done *perfectly*.

Since the only problematic difference between the two versions of your command is the presence or absence of redirections, a better option is to use the `exec` builtin. This command:

```
exec >/dev/null 2>&1
```

redirects the STDOUT and STDERR of the remainder of a shell-script to `/dev/null`. This command:

```
[[ "$IS_VERBOSE" ]] || exec >/dev/null 2>&1
```

will run `exec >/dev/null 2>&1` *unless* `$IS_VERBOSE` is non-blank, in which case it does nothing. (You can replace `[[ "$IS_VERBOSE" ]]` with whatever sort of conditional expression you're already using to detect verbosity.)

So, what you'd want is something like this:

```
(
    [[ "$IS_VERBOSE" ]] || exec >/dev/null 2>&1
    "$PROGRAM" "$ARG1" "$ARG2" &
)
```

The parentheses `( ... )` are to set up a subshell, so the `exec` command (if run) only affects up until the `)`.

(By the way, note that I changed your `2>&1 > /dev/null` to `> /dev/null 2>&1`: the order matters.)

Comment: So, any program executed inside the parentheses `( ... )` will be affected by the `exec` command?

Comment: @VictorHugo: Yes. (More precisely: the `exec` command affects the shell itself. It's as if you simply redirected the rest of the Bash-script up to `)`. Since the commands inside that script inherit their STDIN and STDOUT from it, they're all affected.)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to encode shell syntax into parameter, just put the default destination for each redirection operator in a parameter, and allow a method for overriding the default.

```
# A little bash-specific, but appropriate defaults should exist for the shell
# of your choice.
STDOUT=/dev/stdout
STDERR=/dev/stderr

if some-test; then
    STDOUT=some-other-file
fi

if some-other-test; then
    STDERR=different-file
fi

$PROGRAM $ARG1 $ARG2 > $STDOUT 2> $STDERR
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build any command line you like and then use eval to execute it:

```
line="echo hello"
if ....
    line="$line > junk.out"
fi

eval $line
```

(BUt I would probably go with the 2-line approach you suggest as being easier to read and understand...)